# IE11 iframe flickering in Windows 10 but not Windows 7

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11, flicker

I have a web page that contains an iframe. When users edit in the iframe it does the post back. We have used this with IE11 and Windows 7 for a couple years with no flickering. Now we are updating users to Windows 10 and they are starting to see flickering. Why has it started flickering? How do I stop it? The only change made is updating to Windows 10

Comment: How do you trigger the web page post back event? Can you post the related code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: My code is rather long but the structure of it is that the iframe contains a table with textboxes. The table is built using asp:Repeater with each repeater only having a single row. The post back is triggered through the onChange events that call methods from the code behind. The code behind does some validation and updates a label above the table.

Comment: Without any of code, it is hard t narrow down the problem, so, it is better to create a sample or post related code to reproduce it. Besides, since you are using Iframe tag, please check html resource, whether the element id property changed, it may affect the validation.Besides, I suggest you could refer to [this article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-PostBack-Trigger-Full-PostBack-for-LinkButton-inside-GridView-within-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx), and try to use Ajax UpdataPanel with the Repeater control.

Comment: I created a sample web site on my github to replicate the scenario (https://github.com/MatthewSSizemore/IFrame-Flicker). Would there be any down side to placing an update panel on every input? This seems to be the only way to resolve the issue for every browser.